What does token_type_id affect the self attention and other mechanism in BERT?
I know that BERT use NSP (Next Sentence Prediction) task for pre-training. They design two sentence separated by [SEP] token and have token id different on each sentence.
My downstream task is build a CrossEncoder for classify relevance between a question and information of a passage (a combinations of all entities). So I wonder should I modify the tokenize process. Because If I call the call function the input_token_ids is just the same for all tokens both parts. Btw I need the self cross attention between query and passage tokens. I don't know if they have it in NSP setting.
